# Use state not updating inside switch that is constantly updating

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this program that every time the cart changes it runs. It checks if specific id is in the cart (everything until now is working as intended, if i console log "state" after the for loop it will correctly return the state). Then, I have an if statement that depending on the state value it will set a value on local storage and update setValuePixel.

In both cases, state true or false, the setValuePixel will not update the valuePixel value. The console.log after the set state return false either way.

I'm not sure why this is happening so any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
const RemoveItemsOnDeleteKit = ({children}:any) => {
  const [valuePixel, setValuePixel] = useState<string | null>('false')
  const [val, setVal] = useState<string | null>('')
  const handleEvents = (e: PixelMessage) => {
    switch (e.data.eventName) {
      case 'vtex:cartChanged': {
        const { items } = e.data
        let state = false
        if (items != undefined || items != null) {
          for (let i = 0; i <= items.length; i++) {
            // console.log(items[i])
            if (items[i]?.skuId == "38"){
              state = true
            }
          }
          if (state == true) {
            localStorage.setItem('isKitOnCart', 'true')
            setValuePixel('true')
            console.log('the set value pixel value is ', valuePixel)
          }
          else if(state == false) {
            localStorage.setItem('isKitOnCart', 'false')
            setValuePixel('false')
            console.log("THE SET VALUE PIXEL VALUE IS ", valuePixel)
          }
          else {
            console.log("THE ELSE STATEMETN IS HERE!")
          }
        }
      }
      default: {
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the full component please ?

Comment: 1. The State does not update immediately.

Comment: when you update state and log it just after updating. it will return empty state. even if it is updated it will return empty.

Comment: keep in mind that everything you do after a setState will not be called as it refresh the component